# Colombian married to UK citizen

Tags: visas, uk, colombia

I am Colombian and my husband is a UK citizen but we are living in Colombia. We are planning to visit UK this March but I'm not sure if I need to apply for a tourist visa or if I can just travel with him...

Thanks

Comment: You need a visa.

Answer (score 1):

[UK government's website](https://www.gov.uk/check-uk-visa/y/colombia/tourism) is very good for seeing if you need a Visa.

You will need a [Standard Visitor Visa](https://www.gov.uk/standard-visitor-visa).